# 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.IHubCallerConnectionContext<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Group'

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, signalr-hub

I'am a newbie with signalR in ASP.NET C#.
the problem , I uses state management instead of Group property in Person class.

```
 public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

  //  public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

Client Code to Pass the State

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var broadcaster = $.connection.firstHub;

        broadcaster.client.displayText = function (name, message) {
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + name + ' said: ' + message + '</li>');
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $("#broadcast").click(function () {
                broadcaster.server.join($('#groupName').val());
                broadcaster.state.GroupName = $('#groupName').val();
                 broadcaster.server.broadcastMessage({ Name: $('#name').val(),Message: $('#message').val() });
                broadcaster.server.leave($('#groupName').val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="groupName" />
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="broadcast" value="Broadcast" />

    <ul id="messages"></ul>
</div>
```

Hub Implementation to Use the State Values

```
[HubName("firstHub")]
public class Chapter3Hub : Hub
{
    public void BroadcastMessage(Person person)
    {

    Context.ConnectionId).displayText(person.Name, person.Message);

        Clients.Group(Clients.Caller.GroupName).displayText(person.Name, person.Message);

    }

    public Task Join(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public Task Leave(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }  
}
```

When i run , VS bugs this. 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.IHubCallerConnectionContext' does not contain a definition for 'Group'

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue, but jQuery 1.6.4 is very outdated - almost 7 years in fact. I'd suggest you update it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

hjk , I have modified this line .

```
  Clients.Group((string)Clients.Caller.GroupName).displayText(person.Name, person.Message);
```

and run successfully.